# Sending SMS Error : Invalid or missing integration API Key

Tags: wordpress, 4.7, sms, civisms, clickatell

I just upgraded to 4.7.28 on wordpress 4.9.1 I am trying to setup my Clickatell SMS provider but I am getting a strange error;

[image]

However I have dobble checked the details and have tested it using the URl method:

```
http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&api_id=3591165&to=6785470505&text=Message
```

and that work fine, I am just trying to send indervidual SMS's at the moment.

here are the setting I am using:

[image]

Any help or insight into where things are going wrong would be appriciated

Comment: Hi @Zeak,  in the settings you have a different url as test. The settings URL starts with _platform_ and te thest url starts with _api_. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zeak,

As per Clickatell api [documentation](https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/http-api-send-message/) the api url to send sms is 
  `https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==&to=xxxxxxxxxxx&content=Test+message+text`

Please cross check in clickatell the api key under SMS Integration tab(it should be of 24 chars with '==' at the end).